# Disabling customer health check - Hystrix

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to disable the below listed custom health check for hystrix -

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixHealthIndicator")
public class XspHystrixHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {
```

When I check localhost:8080/health , I see the below

```
{
"status": "UP",
"xspHystrix": {
"status": "UP"
},
"manualSwitch": {
"status": "UP"
},
"redis": {
"status": "UP",
"version": "3.0.7"
},
"hystrix": {
"status": "UP"
}
}
```

I don't want xspHystrix and hystrix to be listed and they shouldn't be part of health check.

I add the below property and don't see hystrix any longer but I still see xspHystrix which I don't want to be displayed -

```
management:
  health:
    hystrix:
      enabled: false
    xspHystrix:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: You should use `health.config.enabled=false`

Comment: I would like disable only for hystrix listed above. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it without changing your code of `XspHystrixHealthIndicator.java`.

**Spring Boot health actuator** aggregates **all Spring beans that implement `HealthIndicator`**. If you put your `XspHystrixHealthIndicator` in component scan path, it will be aggregated into Health actuator.

If you can change `XspHystrixHealthIndicator.java`, please try the below.
First, remove `@Component` and `@ConditionalOnClass` from `XspHystrixHealthIndicator`. And then make your own configuration class that will load your `XspHystrixHealthIndicator` bean based on properties. It might look like something below.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixHealthIndicator")
public class XpsHystrixAutoConfiguration {   
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("xspHystrix")
    public XspHystrixHealthIndicator xpsHystrixHealthIndicator() {
        return new XspHystrixHealthIndicator();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this is exactly the code that I see in autocinfiguation classes for custom health check classes.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/1.3.x/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixAutoConfiguration.java You might aldo need to add @AutoConfigureAfter({ HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class })  if you have ordering issue.